# Installing SystemML from MVN/GitHub?

Tags: r, maven, github, systemml

SystemML is available on https://github.com/SparkTC/systemml
How do I get it started with? I am newbie to GitHub.

I created a directory in my Ubuntu and copied the POM.xml file - when I issued mvn clean package, I am getting the error:

```
mvn clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.ibm.systemml:systemml-parent:5.2-SNAPSHOT (/home/vmuser/system-ml/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Child module /home/vmuser/system-ml/system-ml of /home/vmuser/system-ml/pom.xml does not exist
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
```

When I went to R and issued the following command on R 64 bit ver 3.1.1, I got error too:

```
> install.packages(c("batch", "bitops", "boot", "caTools", "data.table", "doMC", "doSNOW", "ggplot2", "glmnet", "lda", "Matrix", "matrixStats", "moments", "plotrix", "psych", "reshape", "topicmodels", "wordcloud", "methods"), dependencies=TRUE)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1
Warning: package ‘methods’ is in use and will not be installed
Warning message:
packages ‘batch’, ‘bitops’, ‘boot’, ‘caTools’, ‘data.table’, ‘doMC’, ‘doSNOW’, ‘ggplot2’, ‘glmnet’, ‘lda’, ‘Matrix’, ‘matrixStats’, ‘moments’, ‘plotrix’, ‘psych’, ‘reshape’, ‘topicmodels’, ‘wordcloud’ are not available (for R version 3.1.1) 
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you received tells you what the problem is (formatting mine):

> The project `com.ibm.systemml:systemml-parent:5.2-SNAPSHOT` (`/home/vmuser/system-ml/pom.xml`) has 1 error
>
> **Child module `/home/vmuser/system-ml/system-ml` of `/home/vmuser/system-ml/pom.xml` does not exist**

You said:

> I created a directory in my Ubuntu and copied the POM.xml file

You don't just need the `pom.xml` file; you need the whole project. Either `git clone` it or [download the source as a zip](https://github.com/SparkTC/systemml/archive/master.zip) and extract it, then run `mvn clean package` from the project directory.

`git clone` is a better option if you intend to modify the source code. It will give you some powerful tools for integrating upstream changes and for submitting your modifications to the parent project. If you just want to use the project as-is, either option should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

SystemML became an Apache (incubating) project in November of 2015. Its main website is located at http://systemml.apache.org/. The project can now be found on GitHub at https://github.com/apache/incubator-systemml.

Probably the quickest way to get started with Apache SystemML is to download a pre-built release package from the Apache SystemML Downloads page (see the main website). Information about Apache SystemML can be found at the Apache SystemML Documentation site, which is linked to from the main site. This includes information about running SystemML in notebooks, on Spark, and on Hadoop.

If you would like to clone the SystemML repository and build it locally with Maven, instructions to do so can be found in the project README on GitHub.